# Gmail exibindo host de origem no destinatário quando uso mail() do PHP

Tags: php, gmail

Oi, preciso fazer o envio de emails automaticos conforme o usuario solicita. Eu tenho a função que faz esse envio mas no servidor o remetente fica dessa forma no gmail:

> contato@site.com por  br232.hostgator.com.br

preciso dele como se tivesse sido enviado por smtp, é possivel ?

> CONTATO DO SITE (contato@site.com)

Inclusive com o nome do remetente e não só o email, assim:

> [image: Remetente (From) no Gmail]

Explicação do gmail:  http://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=pt-BR

Comment: não, o gmail colocou até uma explicação para isso: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=pt-BR

Comment: coloquei uma img

Comment: uso o email do gmail!

Comment: Ok, entendi o problema, eu editei a minha resposta, por favor tente ela. Editei o titulo da resposta pra ficar um pouco mais intuitiva pra outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema acharem a sua pergunta ;)

Comment: Eu acho que está **faltando uma informação importante** nas respostas dadas até então: o parâmetro adicional `-f` no caso do PHP estar usando o _sendmail_, para setar justamente o host de envio.

Comment: @Bacco não sabia que isso era necessário com SMTP, vou fazer um teste apenas com `mail();` e o Gmail, seu comentário parece um embrião de uma resposta (como diria o bfavaretto)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei postando uma "miniresposta" por ter aparecido uma duplicata com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível solução pra remover isto seria usar o PHPMailer pra fazer o envio.

Primeiro baixe via composer na pasta do seu projeto (seu usar composer):

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

Ou então faça download do último Release em: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases

Se fez o download extraia a pasta `PHPMailer-5.2.14` na pasta que esta o seu script, a estrutura de pasta deve ser algo como:

```
./projeto
    |---- enviaremail.php
    |---- PHPMailer-5.2.14/
            |---- PHPMailerAutoload.php
            |---- ...
```

**enviaremail.php**:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer-5.2.14/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Pra depurar o código remova o // do começo

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Define como SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.exemplo.com';                     // Endereço do SMTP
$mail->Port = 25;                                     // Porta do SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Autenticação no SMTP
$mail->Username = 'contato@exemplo.com';              // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'senha';                            // SMTP password

//$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');       //comentei esta linha pois o Gmail irá detectar se tentar alterar o "from", mas pode tentar

//Adiciona destinatários:

$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Adiciona destinatário
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Destinatário sem nome

$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

//Manda como cópia
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');

//Manda como cópia oculta
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//Anexos se precisar    
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');


//Habilita HTML
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Assunto';
$mail->Body    = 'Mensagem <b>teste</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Mensagem em texto, alternativa ao HTML';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Mensagem enviada';
}
```

Se for usar o Gmail como "remetente" terá que desbloquear nas configurações do Gmail mesmo, as configurações pra usar a sua conta do Gmail pra enviar emails é:

```
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// Se a rede não suportar SMTP sobre IPv6

$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
```

Para outros problemas consulte:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Ok! Funcionou! Vlw!

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [própria documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php), você pode usar parâmetros adicionais para o *mailer* do sistema.

Se o sistema for baseado em *sendmail*, há um parâmetro que pode ajudar, o `-f`:

```
<?php 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-fquem.envia@example.com"); 
?>
```

Isto faz com que o *sendmail* se identifique com o nome indicado, ao fazer a conexão SMTP.

Por padrão, o *sendmail* usa a configuração do OS, e isto é o que gera a divergência dos endereços, e consequentemente faz com que o Google mostre os dois endereços, o "from", que é usado pelo PHP, e o "via", que é retirado da negociação do protocolo. O `-f` faz o *override* deste comportamento.

**Importante:** nem sempre o *sendmail* permite este override. Pode ser necessária alguma configuração extra diretamente no sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Inclua no header as informações desejadas, exemplo:

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.1".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: Meu Nome <eu@seudominio.com>".PHP_EOL; // remetente no LINUX
$headers .= "Return-Path: eu@seudominio.com".PHP_EOL; // return-path
$envio = mail("destinatario@algum-email.com", "Assunto", "Texto", $headers);
```

Veja mais sobre a função `mail` na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mail.php).

Comment: Na verdade a quebra de linha no `\n` vai atender Unix-like e Windows, seria melhor trocar ambas pela constante `PHP_EOL`. Entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Atualizado, obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Editei a resposta, porque `from: foo@foo` e `from: foo <foo@foo>` seria a mesma coisa e o `PHP_EOL` já resolve, na verdade **eu acho** no windows não usa mais \r\n, use o \n mesmo. Somente o editor de texto notepad.exe usa \r\n. Se discordar faça o rollback =)

Comment: aparece o nome do meu host junto do email!!!

Comment: cara, mas no gmail fica assim o remetente "Contato contato@contato.com por br232.hostgator.com.br

Comment: @APS isso é o titulo do email? Você alterou algo no subject? Você cadastrou como contato alguma vez o email?

Comment: não cadastrei como contato o email, o header tá como nesse post:

Comment: $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.1".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8".PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "From: Kloubbe <contato@kloubbe.com>".PHP_EOL; // remetente no LINUX
$headers .= "Return-Path: contato@kloubbe.com".PHP_EOL; // return-path