# Como mudar o parâmetro FROM do envio de email para que não apareça o servidor de envio

Tags: php, vb.net, email

Tenho usado [este](http://pageaffairs.com/notebook/google-apps-spf) tutorial como base, mas ao enviar a mensagem por e-mail (usando PHP) aparece como servidor de envio `io.wv.pt`.

#### Exemplo 1:

[image: Exemplo 1]

#### Exemplo 2:

[image: Exemplo 2]

#### Código PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['postsubmit'])) {
        mail($_POST['to'], $_POST['subject'] , $_POST['mensagem'], 'From: '    .$_POST['email']);
        echo 'sent';
        echo $_POST['mensagem'];
    }
?>
```

Como corrijo isto?

Comment: Já resolvi. Mas não deixou link da pergunta.

Comment: quis dizer no link indicado como duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118364/gmail-exibindo-host-de-origem-no-destinat%c3%a1rio-quando-uso-mail-do-php

Comment: Tem razão.  Pode eliminar esta. Contudo vou fazer outra pergunta porque ao solucionar os meus problemas acho que consigo ajudar outras pessoas que queiram enviar emails.

Comment: Melhor nao eliminar, assim quem procurar acha por uma ou por outra. Essa é justamente a idéia de marcar como duplicata. Mais de um jeito para achar as informações. Assim, formulada de dois jeitos diferentes, as soluções tem mais chance de ser achada.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado na mesma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No quarto parâmetro da função `mail()`, defina o cabeçalho.

```
$to      = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['mensagem'];
$headers = 'From: NOME DE QUEM ENVIA <'.$_POST['email'].'>'.PHP_EOL.
'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Todavia, depende do servidor SMTP (quem envia de fato o email).

O servidor SMTP pode não permitir customizar o nome de quem envia.

Comment: Sim, era isso que me faltava.